# Как соединить строковые переменные?

Tags: bash

Пробую написать небольшой скрипт на bash и уже в самом начале проблема.
Создаю две переменные и пытаюсь их соединить, но вместо этого происходит какая-то ересь, прошу помощи.
Гугл ответа пока не дал.

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR='/test/test/test/conf/'
conf=${DIR}'nginx/test.conf'
echo $conf
```

В результате получаю ответ вида:

> nginx/test.conf/conf/

Как я понял символы второй строки просто перезаписывает символы первой, до тех пор, пока символы второй строки не закончатся. Но как заставить это работать как надо понять не смог.

Пробовал без скобок, с использованием плюса, соединять в двойных кавычках, и подобные способы.

P.S. Строки переписал под тестовые, на деле использую нормальный адрес, но проблема даже с этими строками сохраняется.

Comment: Я не знаю что это за чушь, но костыль найден.
В конец каждой строки добавить знак ";" и все будет хорошо.
Если у кого будет такая же проблема, попробуйте, может и вам поможет.

Comment: Раньше с подобным не сталкивался. Более того, на локальной машине и на [ideone](https://ideone.com/vPE3ru) код работает верно. Но если Вы нашли решение, пожалуйста, оставьте его в виде ответа, так будет проще людям, которые обратятся с подобной проблемой.

Comment: проблема не воспроизводится. в качестве гипотезы: возможно, в файл попали «не те» переводы строк. в *ms/windows* это `\r\n`, в *macos* — `\r`, в *gnu/linux* — `\n`. правда, воссоздать встреченную вами ошибку мне так и не удалось.

Comment: Да, похоже проблема в том что все делалось на винде, через ide netbeans, а в качестве терминала использовался cygwin. Ide я написал тоже, так как скрипт был записан в sh файле, и только потом запущен через консоль на виртуалке с линуксом.
Soon, хорошо, ответ постараюсь оформить по понятнее, может ещё у кого будут такие проблемы (сам больше часа на поиск решения потратил, пока не заметил что можно принудительно завершить строку символом точки с запятой).
Спасибо всем кто прочитал и попробовал решить и разобраться в проблеме.

Comment: На всякий случай `tr -d '\r'` удаляет CR (все), поэтому более правильно `sed 's/\r$//'` (ну и  почитайте man для tr и sed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения проблемы нужно каждую логическую строку закончить символом точки с запятой '**;**'.
Прочитав комментарии понял что проблема кроется в одном или сразу всех далее следующих факторах.
Баг появляется если работать в **windows**, писать **скрипт в файле**, через ide, в данном случае netbeans, но возможно и фв других **ide** повторится, и запускать его через **cygwin** консоль, возможно так же повторится и в других подобных терминалах.
Пример рабочего скрипта.

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR='/test/test/test/conf/';
conf=${DIR}'nginx/test.conf';
echo $conf;
```

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте сделать так

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/test/test/test/conf"
conf="${DIR}/nginx/test.conf"
echo $conf
```

**UPD**

Воссоздал ситуацию.
Такое поведение возникает если скрипт записан следующим образом:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR='/test/test/test/conf/'\r\n
conf=${DIR}'nginx/test.conf'
echo $conf
```

Но для того, чтобы его так записать, надо еще постараться.

Вот пример:

```
echo '#!/bin/bash\nDIR="/test/test/test/conf"\r\nconf=${DIR}"nginx/test.conf"\necho $conf' > script
```

Comment: Проблема у ТС *не в тексте скрипта*, там *все правильно* (копипаста в Linux работает).